# In ADO.Net, iterating over a loop inside a sql connection is causing error

Tags: sql, .net, .net-core, ado.net

I am writing a program to maintain an inventory of medicine in our store.

I have a Add to cart list, which opens up the SQL connection and delete 1 quantity from the entire stock where the parameter is `@medicine`

My addToCart listBox's code looks like this

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cstring))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Medicine set Quantity = Quantity - 1 where Name = @medicine", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach(string item in cartMedicine)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicine", item);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
        listMedicine.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now I want to loop my `cartMedicine` list to get all the names stored in the listbox one by one. But I am getting the error message that,

> The variable name '@medicine' has already been declared. Variable names
> must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.'

How can I use the same logic of giving an Adhoc statement each time for each inventory in my Item's list?

Comment: I suggest you use a Table Valued Parameter to do this in bulk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the parameter over and over again but add it once and then just set its value. ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) anyway.

```
...
SqlParameter sqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@medicine", SqlDbType.<data type>, <length>)
foreach (string item in cartMedicine)
{
    sqlParameter.Value = item;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
```

Replace `<data type>` and `<length>` with the proper values for the data type of `medicine.quantity` in the database.